# How do I add an item to the front of a state array in React

Tags: reactjs

I know that you can add items to the end of the array with `concat` but how do I unshift to add an item to the front?

Add to the end:

```
var allStatuses = this.state.statusData;
var newStatuses = allStatuses.concat([data.statuses]);
this.setState({statusData: newStatuses});
```

What I want to do is change the "concat" to something that will put data.statuses to the front and not the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually you can use `.concat` in this case,

```
var newStatuses = [data.statuses].concat(allStatuses);
```

Answer (score 22):

Is there a problem doing

```
[data.statuses].concat(allStatuses);
```

If you are using ES6, you can do

```
var newStatuses = [data.statuses, ...allStatuses]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify the original array, use [Array.unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.unshift(0);
arr // 0,1,2,3
```

If you want a new array, use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) as [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903967/227299) suggested

```
this.setState({statusData: [0].concat(this.state.statusData)})
```

Which is similar to spreading into a new array

```
this.setState({statusData: [0, ...this.state.statusData]})
```